# Page settings for an app

Tags: facebook, user-interface, interface

We have a facebook app that we have created for people to use on their organization's pages (not personal accounts), and in the past when they wanted to adjust the settings they would go onto the page, go to edit settings, and go to the appropriate app. It would take them to a /settings page that was built into the canvas app.

I can't find where that menu chain is anymore. Edit Settings no longer has anything about apps in it unless I'm on a personal page.

Where do I find this information now?

Thanks!

Edit: For clarification, the place I'm trying to go to is called the 'Page Tab Edit URL'.

**Double Edit**: I posted a question on the facebook help community - haven't seen anything there either https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151539448667919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page having the app click `Edit Page` and then select `Edit settings`.

On the Settings page click `more...` (under the page name) and select `apps`.
Now you have the old app list with the link to `go to app`.

Comment: Wow, I wish they'd had this when they first rolled that layout out. Thanks guys!